# Two FloatingActionButton in a Column position is not default

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

The position of floating action button is not in the default position, when i use it in a Column to use two FloatingActionButton

What do i do...?

How to make it in the default position..?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by `default` and what you are getting

Comment: a sample code-snippet with desire output image will be better

Comment: add some code for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Default `Column`'s  `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`. Using  `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` will serve the thing you are trying to get.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
      FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {})
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: glad to help, it would be understandable for everyone if would add sample image and code snippet, you can find more about [asking goog question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation

> Use at most a single floating action button per screen. Floating
> action buttons should be used for positive actions such as "create",
> "share", or "navigate".

Do it in right way. Use RawMaterialButton and style it as you wish.